# Measurement of delay between two signals using MSO4104 with PyVisa

Tags: python, automation, measurement, pyvisa

I need to automate the measurement of delay between two signals using the oscilloscope. I am using MSO4104 from Tektronix. I programmed the oscilloscope for delay measurement, but I am not getting the output.

The measurement conditions are given below:

Signal 1

High-90%,Mid,20% Low 10% and EDGE-Falling

Signal-2 Low 10% ,Mid 20%, High 90 EDGE Raising

Please see my code below. After executing this code output is not coming.

Can you please tell me where I went wrong?

```
import pyvisa
from time import *
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
#print(rm.list_resources())
scope = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x0699::0x0401::C002760::0::INSTR')
IDN = scope.query('*IDN?')
print ('Successfully connected to: ', IDN)
scope.write("*RST")
scope.write('SELECT:CH1 ON')
scope.write('SELECT:CH2 ON')
scope.write("AUTOset EXECute")
sleep(5)
scope.write("MEASUrement:REFLevel:METHod PERCent")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:IMMED:DELAY:DIRECTION FORWARDS")
#For Channel_1

scope.write("MEASUrement:IMMed:SOURCE CH1")
scope.write("MEASUrement:IMMed:DELay:EDGE1 FALL")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:REFLEVEL:PERCENT:HIGH 90")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:REFLEVEL:PERCENT:MID 20")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:REFLEVEL:PERCENT:LOW 10")
#For Channel_2
scope.write("MEASUrement:IMMed:SOURCE CH2")
scope.write("MEASUrement:IMMed:DELay:EDGE2 RISE")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:REFLEVEL:PERCENT:LOW 3")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:REFLEVEL:PERCENT:MID 20")
scope.write("MEASUREMENT:REFLEVEL:PERCENT:HIGH 80")
sleep(10)
scope.write("MEASure:DELay CH1,CH2")
sleep(10)
Delay_1_2 = scope.query('MEASure:DELay? CHANNEL1,CHANNEL2')
print('Delay is:',Delay_1_2)
scope.close()
rm.close()
```

Comment: Check commands once more. Maybe you should use either short form or long form commands consistently. In addition I cannot find MEASURE:DELAY? CHANNEL1, CHANNEL2 -command in the manual (usually channels are specified as CH<x>). Maybe you should check that one..

Comment: Thank you.I will check it and let you know.

Comment: Usually I first implement measurement manually, and then I automate it. Sometimes commands required are not easy to guess...

Comment: Manually it is working fine.I think the order of my command execution is not proper.Need to check.